# Google app Script: URL of Sites get bad to google mail

Tags: email, url, google-apps-script, outlook

I'm working in a Google App Script, that sends a congrats card (made in Sites) to multiple emails.  The situation is: The card is bad sent to Google emails and good sent to outlook emails.  The reason is that the url of "sites" gets modified with gmail and not with outlook!

What is the reason? Can someone help me?

Comment: can you describe the differences in the urls?

Comment: In outlook get as https://sites.google.com/a/eforcers.com/tarjeta/_/rsrc/1346783002540/tarjetaelectronica1/hb.gif in google looks like this "<img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/k5T4LQJZxr7aD08fGhHsRa6iO7WeXVu4aSKbSdKk9pJhyv3ntq2f7funsjbUKJCa8kEyW7m8t9MjBTwgIwQ5RPjTc2lXkVESZcJvruPie9HHEnqWeuczVKPTIW55x-srgfbO7H42WkxnWo5ytzgrq60NeSdR=s0-d-e1-ft#https://sites.google.com/a/eforcers.com/tarjeta/_/rsrc/1346783002540/tarjetaelectronica1/hb.gif" border="0" class="CToWUd"

Comment: You first need to test whether the problem is the Apps Script code, or something else.  If you manually send an email from Gmail, does it work?  If you send an email the normal way, without Apps Script, and it works then there is something wrong with Apps Script.  If it's the Apps Script, we need to see your code.  If there is nothing wrong with the code, then it's a bug from Google, and should be reported.  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send the email as an htmlbody, your css styles and all that will be ignored by outlook, DEPENDING on the security settings or policies imposed by the company IT.

This I know as I have a script that simply sends an anchor link styled to look like a button.  when we receive it in outlook, it is displayed simply as text with highlighting (no padding, no whatever), although the link works.  But if opened through gmail, it looks like it should.

And the fault was not with Apps Script bec then, it should also look bad in Gmail and not only in outlook.